# Does steganography ensure confidentiality?

Tags: confidentiality, steganography

Can we say that steganography ensures confidentiality? I think it does not ensure because it is based on the **security through obscurity** and then it does not respect **Kerckhoffs's principles**, but the notion of confidentiality being highly subjective, I would appreciate any answer.

Comment: Similar to 'user52472' you will want to look at another approach instead of using a solution of steganography. You will want to instead look at appropriate access control models, in this case, only ensuring that access to the data/information is only for those with the correct access to the correct level of confidentiality. For example, you may have a document where you only want Person A and B from Department A can access the document from Building A, but not when Person A from Department is accessing from home (as doing so, would increase risk for the confidential document)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steganography solves a different problem.  Steganography attempts to hide the existence of the data at all, not necessarily protect the confidentiality of the data once it's discovered.

[Regarding Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle#Explanation_of_the_principle), yes, steganography does violate Kerckhoff's principle.  Specifically, point 2:

> It should not require secrecy, and it should not be a problem if it falls into enemy hands;

Steganography does not use a key, and as such requires that the method of encoding data remain secret.

Comment: “Steganography does not use a key” — is that true by definition? Because I don’t think it is: steganography *could* require a key … with (theoretically) plausible deniability, by making a wrong key on hidden data behave the same way as on no hidden data.

Comment: -1 You can absolutely use steganography that does not violate Kerckhoff's principle. The algorithm used can _certainly_ be public, as long as the medium you are hiding in has a sufficiently predictable distribution that you can hide data in it such that a key is needed to discover its existence. An analogous technique used by the military (and civilians, at times) is LPD FHSS, a radio communication technique which blends in with background radiation perfectly unless a specific frequency hopping sequence is known.